# Need to implement slider in android

Tags: android, android-sliding

I want to implement slider which automatic slider after some time and also slider by user touch (like running in web sites).

I had try so many things but not use full to me.

**what  i'm trying:**

```
<linearlayout =1 />
<linearlayout =2 />
<linearlayout =3 />
```

i'm inflating **layout 2** with below xml

```
<linearlayout>
     <imageview>
     <webview>
</linearlayout>
```

**Inflating xml depend from web service data which come from server.**

and need to implement slider functionality in layout 2.

SO need way hoe to achieve this task in android for now i had already try so many thing but not use full top me.

Comment: Sliding which way, vertically or horizontally? Why do `ViewPager` and `SlidingDrawer` not fit your needs?

Comment: did you try scrollview ?